# Merge multiple log files into a single one based on timestamp

Tags: shell, logging

I'm trying to find a solution to fastly merge 2 log files coming from 2 application servers.
The log files is like this:

```
00:00:00,028 DEBUG [com.acme.productionservice...
```

I would like something that based on the time stamp print one line of the log file or another for example:

if file one have 2 lines:

```
00:00:00,028 DEBUG [com.acme.productionservice...
00:00:00,128 DEBUG [com.acme.productionservice...
```

and file two have this 3 lines:

```
00:00:00,045 DEBUG [com.acme.productionservice...
00:00:00,100 DEBUG [com.acme.productionservice...
00:00:00,150 DEBUG [com.acme.productionservice...
```

the output should be

```
00:00:00,028 DEBUG [com.acme.productionservice...   (file 1)
00:00:00,045 DEBUG [com.acme.productionservice...   (file 2)
00:00:00,100 DEBUG [com.acme.productionservice...   (file 2)
00:00:00,128 DEBUG [com.acme.productionservice...   (file 1)
00:00:00,150 DEBUG [com.acme.productionservice...   (file 2)
```

the only way I currently know is using 
    cat file1 file | sort
but this is very slow for gb of logs
I need something like reading the 2 files and compare the timestamps and decide what to print.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/148456/merging-and-sorting-multiple-files-with-sort

Comment: can I retire the question ? :)

Comment: @marcobazzani, you should provide your own answer to this question, so other's can benefit from what you learned. Presumabley, that's `sort -m file1 file2 > file3`. If you want to delete your own question, you can do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up by using

```
sort -m
```

I also used a trick to understand from which log file the log comes from with

```
for a in *.log ; do 
    awk  '$0=FILENAME" "$0' $a > $a.log
do
sort -m -k 2 *.log.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [*Super Speedy Syslog Searcher*](https://crates.io/crates/super_speedy_syslog_searcher)

(assuming you have [rust installed](https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install))

```
cargo install super_speedy_syslog_searcher
```

then

```
s4 log1 log2
```

However, *Super Speedy Syslog Searcher* expects to find a *date*time stamp. If you can change the logging format from timestamp to datetimestamp then `s4` can sort and merge the lines.